# Load Different View Controllers in the Master-Detail App template

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode4.3, master-detail

I am developing a master detail application using Xcode 4.3.3, now in the master view controller i have managed to load an additional view controller called "Fav Real"
When this view controller loads, it will contain different items taken from an sqlite database into a tableViewController.
 My problem is here, i need when i click on any loaded row, to load a different viewController into the detailViewController, to load another view controller instead of the first one.
 I am actually lost, i tried to do the following schema but i have no idea how to do my goal...Any help will be highly appreciated.[image]

As it shows, the items will load correctly in the FavReal tableView , but my goal is when i click at any row, the "Details" showing in the right will load instead of the DetailsViewController.
I tried this code in the FavReal.m but i always get : " Application tried to push a nil view controller on target .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 Details * vc4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc4 animated:YES];

}
```

Thank you for your time, if any further details are needed please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone was having the same problem as i was, the only solution i found is not to load a different view controller and replace the original detailViewController, but the actual solution was to create a new storyboard and make it appear when the Favorites button is clicked, this way you'll have a nice stylish effect and keep your data presentation accurate. To do so use the following lines of code :

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController* initialHelpView = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

initialHelpView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:initialHelpView animated:YES];
```

You have the freedom to change the modal presentation as u prefer.
Best of luck